# Duplicate symbols between CardboardSDK and GTMSessionFetcher, is there anyway to fix this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-vr, gtmsessionfetcher

I'm trying to add GVRSDK to my iOS app but as soon as i add it, linking error appear with multiple duplicates between the GVRSDK and GTMSessionFetcher that is used in my application by another pod.
I can't remove the GTMSessionFetcher as some other pods are using it and i'm not able to remove the referencing of it also from the libCardboardSDK.a.

Comment: Could you show your PodFile and the pointing out the two pods causing the issue? Don't they specify in their pod spec their dependency on that vendor library?

Comment: This is my PodFile
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'Mantle-HAL', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'ICViewPager'
    pod 'IDMPhotoBrowser'
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'TwitterCore'
    pod 'YSLTransitionAnimator'
    pod 'GVRSDK'

Mainly "Google/SignIn" and "GVRSDK" are the conflicting ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design issue in the googleVR SDK.
I've reported the bug there and an issue has been created.Let's wait for them to fix it.
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/163

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the projects/sources for the .a? can you make sure they use the `@rpath` as their install name and set the `@rpath` correctly for all of them? Then you can make sure they all look for their `.dylib`/`.framework` dependencies in e.g. `MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/` and then put only one copy of GTMSessionFetcher's framework in there and have all others link to that.

If the projects you're referencing have been set up correctly according to Apple's guidelines, that should just mean you set the @`rpath` in your main application and it should all resolve itself, IIRC (been a while since we did that and we weren't using CocoaPods, so not sure if that does something that would prevent that from working).

Comment: From my understanding @rpath is only for mac development not for iOS.
In my app, the two conflicting pods are  "Google/SignIn" and "GVRSDK".

Comment: Ah. It says nowhere that this is about iOS, sorry.